# How to create variable glyph width while maintaining the same x height in Illustrator or Indesign

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, font-manipulation

Does anyone know a way to adjust the glyph width while maintaining the same x-height in Illustrator or InDesign?

I am looking to create this effect:

[image: Image example Adobe InDesign or Illustrator]

Similarly, it appears that the strokes of the characters in the image above are changed midway through the "bulge".

I've tried achieving this effect through Illustrator, creating outline and then adjusting them but I was wondering if there is an alternative method.

Answer (score 2):

Set text and then choose `Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Mesh` configure the mesh so you have 1 row and 2 columns. This provides a mesh line in the middle of the text. More columns will provide addition mesh lines for more alterations.

Then it's a matter of selecting mesh points and double-clicking the **Scale Tool** to adjust how the mesh alters the text.

[image]